# RobolectricTestRunner fails when config sdk target is set

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I am testing for notifications. If I don't specify config sdk target the test passes. But if I specify targets the test fails and I don't know why.

The piece that fails is

```
@Mock private NotificationManager mockNotificationManager;
....

@Test
  public void testNotificationWorks() throws Exception {
    ...
    verify(mockNotificationManager)
        .notify(ID, any());
  }
```

and the config setting causing the issue is `@Config(sdk = { 20, 26 })`

All my other tests continue to pass. Only the one about notification fails and here is the error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked: 
Wanted but not invoked:
mockNotificationManager.notify(
    Localized: 2721,
    Localized: <any>
);
```

Also I play around with the values inside `@Config(sdk = { min, max })` but the only thing that works is if I comment out the line.

Comment: Not sure whether thats a `roboelectric` feature, but in the standarad `mockito` version you are unable to pass `non-matchers` (`2721`) and `matchers` (`any()`) together as parameters to a mocked function. However in that case `mockito` normally shows an explicit message that you use it incorrectly.

Comment: I am looking but no clear answer jumps at me yet. Any ideas how I might fix the problem? Thanks